# Pandas dataframe - multiplying DF's elementwise on same dates - something wrong?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, alignment, multiplication, resampling

I've been banging my head over this, I just cannot seem to get it right and I don't understand what is the problem... So I tried to do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import quandl

btc_usd_price_kraken = quandl.get('BCHARTS/KRAKENUSD', returns="pandas")
btc_usd_price_kraken.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
plt.plot(btc_usd_price_kraken.index, btc_usd_price_kraken['Weighted Price'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("btc_usd_price_kraken")
plt.show()

eur_usd_price = quandl.get('BUNDESBANK/BBEX3_D_USD_EUR_BB_AC_000', returns="pandas")
eur_dkk_price = quandl.get('ECB/EURDKK', returns="pandas")
usd_dkk_price = eur_dkk_price / eur_usd_price

btc_dkk = btc_usd_price_kraken['Weighted Price'] * usd_dkk_price
plt.plot(btc_dkk.index, btc_dkk) # WHY IS THIS [4785 rows x 1340 columns] ???
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("Historic value of 1 BTC converted to DKK")
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the comment, I don't understand why I get a result (which I'm trying to plot) that has size: [4785 rows x 1340 columns] ?

Anyway, the code results in a lot of error messages, something like e.g.

```
    > Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    > "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py",
    > line 197, in __draw_idle_agg
    >     FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
...
    >     return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 254, in
    > _from_ordinalf
    >     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC) ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

I read some posts and I know that Pandas/Dataframe when using multiply is able to automatically only do an elementwise multiplication, on data-pairs, where the date is the same (so if one DF has timeseries for e.g. 1999-2017 and the other only has e.g. 2012-2015, then only common dates between 2012-2015 will be multiplied, i.e. the intersection subset of the data set) - so this problem about understanding the error message(s) (and the solution) - the whole problem is related to calculating btc_dkk variable and plotting it (which is the price for Bitcoin in the currency DKK)...

Comment: Some sample data in text format along with expected output would be nice if you could add it to the question.

Comment: Hi CS. Thanks for your comment. I have now cleaned up the question a little + now I include a bit of the error message I received and which I couldn't solve (because I didn't understand - still not completely understand - the shape of 4785 x 1340 for the "btc_dkk"-variable. I would expect a dataframe consisting of dates (the intersection of the whole dataset) and the Forex product (btcusd * usddkk) - a vector - not a matrix...

Comment: I would expect some input as text and expected output added to your question...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what kind of text input/output you expect? If you run the code, it'll download what we need and produce a graph as output. No input or output text is involved. The quandl-library (get-function) takes care of this...?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Well, it would've been easier if you had posted snippets of the downloaded dataframes to work with along with what you wanted the output to be, rather than having make users download it themselves and figure out what you want.

Comment: Or maybe it would have made things unnecessary complicated... Anyway, there was a good, fast and correct solution given by user3212593, so I'm grateful for that. I tried to upvote, but apparantly my user account and ranking is too low...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
usd_dkk_price.multiply(btc_usd_price_kraken['Weighted Price'], axis='index').dropna()
```

You are multiplying on columns, not index (this happens since you are multiplying a dataframe and a series, if you had selected the column in usd_dkk_price, this would not have happened). Then afterwards just drop the rows with NaN.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just upvoted - and compared the resulting graph with this one: https://www.coingecko.com/en/price_charts/bitcoin/dkk - the graphs look very very similar, so thanks a lot! I'll reply later today with further comments (as I don't have much time right now). Thanks, man!

Comment: I've read more now - trying to understand... I don't understand this line, sorry: " if you had selected the column in usd_dkk_price, this would not have happened" - could you please write an example of this? Just to learn from, that would be perfect, thanks!

Comment: When you multiply a dataframe and a series, like you did, the series index will be matched on columns not the index (the same happens if you change axis to 'columns' in my proposed solution). That's why the returned data was so wide. What you wanted was to match the index of the dataframe on the index of the series. If you had taken usd_dkk_price[column name] * btc_usd_price_kraken['Weighted Price'], it would have matched on index since it's two series.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I understand. I also accepted the answer, it's great - thanks for your help, now I must practice working with dataframes and series some more...